# shutdown kvm-guests without libvirt/virsh

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

We use kvm on ubuntu 10.4 as virtualisation-solution (we have bash-scripted the whole networking, subneting, starting of vms.....

Is there a way to shutdown a kvm-guest without the usage of libvirt/virsh? A bash or python based solution would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have started your VM with the monitor option (-monitor unix:/tmp/file.mon,server,nowait ), you can stop it by using `echo 'system_powerdown' | socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/file.mon`.

It send a ACPI signal to the VM, which can use it as you push your power button, and then do a shutdown.

Comment: The **socat** command wasn't installed by default on my Fedora (F14) box, but was available in the main repos. I'd never heard of **socat**, it's similar to **netcat** (nc). More info can be found on it's [main site](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). Also this [serverfault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/246347/whats-the-difference-between-socat-and-netcat) was helpful in understanding the differences b/w **netcat** and **socat**.